# Why doesn't Mathematica solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to use `Solve` in Mathematica to get the $x$ and $U$ parameters here but the solution doesn't come out. The program continues running forever. Any ideas? Wolfram Alpha solves the problem easily.

Program: Variables first and then I use `Solve`.

```
P = 0.5;
theta = 74*Pi/180;
muL1 = -30;
muL2 = -200;
eps = -800;
time = 2.418884326505*^-17;
Hartree = 27211.4;
h = (1*^9)*2*time*Hartree*Pi;
```

```
NSolve[x*P*Cos[theta]*Log[(muL1 - eps - U)^2/(muL1 - eps)^2] == 2*Pi*h*(15.883 - 14.9265) && 
  x*P*Cos[theta]*Log[(muL2 - eps - U)^2/(muL2 - eps)^2] == 2*Pi*h*(15.883 - 14.6216), {x, U}]
```

Comment: Use `NSolve[{eq1,eq2},{x,U},Reals]` then it solves it.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e03I.png)  **Wolfram Alpha solves the problem easily**  Wolfram Alpha uses A.I. so may be it tried this on its own. Hard to know.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know Wolfram alpha uses A.I....

Comment: @Nasser To be clear, W|A is built on [GOFAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOFAI).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is by @Nasser in the comments. Another one is to use [Rationalize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

Coefficients

```
P = 0.5;
theta = 74*Pi/180;
muL1 = -30;
muL2 = -200;
eps = -800;
time = 2.418884326505*^-17;
Hartree = 27211.4;
h = (1*^9)*2*time*Hartree*Pi;
```

Equations

```
eq1 = x*P*Cos[theta]*Log[(muL1 - eps - U)^2/(muL1 - eps)^2] == 
    2*Pi*h*(15.883 - 14.9265) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
eq2 = x*P*Cos[theta]*Log[(muL2 - eps - U)^2/(muL2 - eps)^2] == 
    2*Pi*h*(15.883 - 14.6216) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
```

`Solve` instead of `NSolve`

```
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, U}, Reals]
```

you get your solutions like that as well.

Note that using `Reals` is also pivotal here.

Comment: Thank you so much!